# How to put retrieved documents in Hashmap

Tags: java, lucene

I'm working on Lucene Library, and I found the documents required after executing a BooleanQuery.
I looped in the searcher and each time I would like to put the Document in a HashMap.

```
int docId = hits[i].doc;
Document doc = searcher.doc(docId);
HashMap X = new HashMap ();
```

Now I want to know how to fill the hashmap X with the name_Field and the value_Field of the document?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over document fields like this:

```
for (IndexableField field : doc.getFields())
{
    X.put(field.name(), field.stringValue());
}
```

But it will work only for fields which are stored in index (those which was added with Field.Store.YES flag). Also if you have several values for the field in the document this code has to be modified.

Answer (score 0):

You could extends the lucene Collector then add the document as the way you want.

```
 IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader);
 private Map<String, String> docs = new HashMap<String, String>();
 searcher.search(query, new Collector() {
 private int docBase;

 // ignore scorer
 public void setScorer(Scorer scorer) {
 }

 // accept docs out of order (for a BitSet it doesn't matter)
 public boolean acceptsDocsOutOfOrder() {
     return true;
 }

 public void collect(int docNum) {
     Document luceneDoc = searcher.doc(doc + docBase);
     docs.put(luceneDoc.getValues(name_Field), luceneDoc.getValues(value_Field));
 }

 public void setNextReader(AtomicReaderContext context) {
     this.docBase = context.docBase;
 }
});
```